# how to get same date in string and nsdate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have Issue in dateformatter. I add my code as below:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Current Date: %@",currentDate); //Current Date: 2016-10-14 08:07:15 +0000

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSString *tzName = [timeZone name];
NSLog(@"Current TimeZone: %@",tzName); //Current TimeZone: Asia/Kolkata

NSTimeZone *systemTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSString *SyTZName = [systemTimeZone name];
NSLog(@"System TimeZone: %@",SyTZName); //System TimeZone: Asia/Kolkata

NSString *strCurrentDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Current Date: %@",strCurrentDate);//Current Date: 2016-10-14 08:07:47 +0000

NSDateFormatter* localDateFrm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[localDateFrm setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"IST"]];
[localDateFrm setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString* local_string = [localDateFrm stringFromDate:currentDate];
 NSLog(@"local_string: %@",local_string);//local_string: 14-10-2016 01:37 PM

NSDateFormatter* local_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;

[local_dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"IST"]];
[local_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [local_dateFormatter dateFromString:local_string];
NSLog(@"date : %@",date);//date : 2016-10-14 08:07:00 +0000
```

at last I need  `01:37 PM` but I get `08:07:00 +0000`.when I convert string into NSDate its not give me expected reply(01:37 PM). so the time is different.
so please help me for this.
Thanks.

Comment: `2016-10-14 08:07:00 +0000` (as NSDate) should be equals to `2016-10-14 13:37:00 +0330` (or -0330, I never know, as NSDate).

Comment: `NSDate` is in GMT format (i think), it only convert if you convert it into string

Comment: when i got string it give me right answer but when i convert same string into nsdate then its changed. actually i need to use this nsdate for UIlocalnotification.firedate

Comment: @PALAKiOSDeveloper you got a date as string in local_string then why u again convert this string into date just simply send into you UIlocalnotification.firedate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDate` will always return `utc` or `gmt` date, if you want it to in your local timezone then you need to convert it to string with `stringFromDate` method of `NSDateFormatter`.

So, when you want to display your date with your local timezone just convert it to `string` and then show. And when you want it to as `NSDate` you can easily convert string to date with `dateFromString` method and it will return date in `utc or gmt` again.

And usually you need to display your date in `label` or any `UI` so you must need string, you can't show `nsdate` on label. So, this is standard approach to deal with `NSDate`

**Update :**

You can use this date as `localnotification`'s firedate also. execute below demo,

```
  NSString *str = @"2016-10-14 08:07:00";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"date : %@",[df dateFromString:str]);


UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

notification.fireDate = date;
notification.alertTitle = @"title";

NSLog(@"notification : %@",notification);
```

and check log for notification, it will show firetime as per your local timezone!!

Second thing you can set `timezone` also for notification like `notification.timeZone = ...;`

Comment: Thx for your reply. I know that if I need to display date on label or any UI that time I need only string. but in my issue i need NSdate because i want to use it in UIlocalNotification. (UILocalNotification.firedate = [ITS ONLY TAKE NSDATE NOT STRING]).